# Adding a <img> to an div tag

Tags: jquery, html, image

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="eventIcons">Sample Event</div>
```

How do I add an  tag to the div before the text so that I end up with:

```
<div class"eventIcons"><img id="printOnlyIcon" src"printOnly.jpg"/>Sample Events</div>
```

I am currently using the following jquery but its adding the  tag after the text:

```
$('div.eventIcons').append('<img id="printOnlyIcon" src="printOnly.jpg"/>');
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`.prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add element at the beginning.

See below,

```
$('div.eventIcons').prepend('<img id="printOnlyIcon" src="printOnly.jpg"/>');
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but now the <img> tag is no longer being added

Comment: @DanielPerez I am not sure why it didn't work for you.. It would be easy for us if you can demonstrate the issue in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1):

Just use "prepend" instead of "append".

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('div.eventIcons').prepend('<img id="printOnlyIcon" src="printOnly.jpg"/>');
```

You have to prepend the imag to your div inorder to append it.